# Difference between 犹如 vs 有如

Tags: grammar, word-choice

What is the difference between 犹如　　vs  有如?
They seem to mean the same thing, are they also the same meaning as 象　?
My Chinese is not good enough to understand dictionary translations.
Thank you :)

Comment: Since ＂Chinese Language Stack Exchange is a question and answer site for students, teachers, and linguists wanting to discuss the **finer points** of the Chinese language.＂it would seem that users might be expected to be able to use dictionaries.

Answer (score 2):

**[犹](http://www.cantonese.sheik.co.uk/dictionary/characters/895/)** carries the meaning of 'like'

**[如](http://www.cantonese.sheik.co.uk/dictionary/characters/503/)** also carries the meaning of 'like'

From my answer to another question:

> *Put two characters with similar meaning together and create a compound word can remove ambiguity. It is very common in coining Chinese words . For example: Both 刚 and 才 carry other meanings, (刚 also means 'hard'; 才 also means 'talent') but '刚才' can only mean 'just'.*

'**犹如**' is a compound word of two characters that carry the meaning of 'like'; 'as if'

> 有
>
> *have/ possess*
>
> '有如'(possess the similar quality) = 'like' ; 'as if'

The two terms seem to be interchangeable, different only in etmology

Examples sentences:

1. **犹如**把錢扔進大海 (**Like**/ **As if** throw money into the sea)
2. **有如**把錢扔進大海 (**Like**/ **As if** throw money into the sea)

Comment: I can't agree with " 如 means 'equal to' or 'as same as' ",  1. when 如 used as a single word, it means 'according to; as; as if; for instance; like; such as;', 2. when used like 犹如，both 犹 and 如 mean 'like, similar to, just like, as', so '犹如' means 'similar to' / 'like', and more (metaphorically) similar than just single word 犹 or 如.

Comment: 如 has more than one meaning, 'equal to'  and 'as same as' are not wrong ('equal to' is not exactly the same' ). But from my answer to another question  : *Put two characters with similar meaning together and create a compound word can remove ambiguity. It is very common in coining Chinese words . For example: Both 刚 and 才 carry other meanings, (刚 also means 'hard'; 才 also means 'talent') but '刚才' can only mean 'just'*. -- 犹如 too, seem to be a compound word of two similar characters that carry the meaning of 'like'

Comment: I don't think put " 二二如四 (2 X 2 = 4) , 如 means 'equal to' or 'as same as' " here is helpful for understand. 如 in 犹如 is also means 'like, similar to'.

Comment: I completely changed my answer, thanks for  reminding me

Answer (score 1):

With similar meaning, 犹如 is used more widely than 有如， which is only found in the writings like  the Four Classics, as far as I know.

Answer (score 0):

As a Chinese student, I also can't tell them exactly 
犹如=好像（as if）
有如=就像（be like）[image][image]